# Let $\{E_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ measurable sets in $[0,1]$ s.t. $\mu(E_n)\ge 1 - \frac{1}{3^n}$, $\Rightarrow \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n \neq \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{E_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of measurable sets in $[0,1]$ s.t. $\mu(E_n)\ge 1 - \frac{1}{3^n}\,\,$, show that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n \neq \emptyset$

Now, we can equivalently prove that $\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n) \neq 0$. I can see why this happens, since $1 - \frac{1}{3^n}$ is monotonically increasing and $\mu([0,1])=1$, but I could not set up a proper proof:

I can observe that $\bigcap_{n=1}^k E_n = [0,1] \setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^k E_n$, hence $$\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n) = \mu([0,1] \setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^k E_n) = 1-\sum_{n=1}^k \mu(E_n) \le 1 - \sum_{n=1}^k (1 - \frac{1}{3^n})= 1-k-\frac{1}{2}(3^{-k}-1)$$
but it doesn’t lead to anything, any suggestion?

Comment: you can probably use that $(\bigcap E_n)^C = \bigcup E_n^C$

Comment: Your inequality is wrong. Minus sign reverses the inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$[0,1]\setminus \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} ([0,1]\setminus E_n)$$
so
$$1 - \mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n) = \mu([0,1]\setminus \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu([0,1]\setminus E_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n} < 1$$
and $\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n) > 0$.